# RewriteEngine .htaccess rules end up redirecting to example.net/https:/example.net

Tags: htaccess, redirects, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm starting to learn about the Apache `.htaccess` and I have some issues in my website...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.net$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !myfolder-public/
RewriteRule (.*) /myfolder-public/$1 [L]
```

The second `RewriteRule` exists because I need a different folder (called `myfolder-public`) to redirect my domain, but when I put this on web browser: `example.com` without HTTPS the page redirects to: `example.net/https:/example.net` and I don't know how to fix that, any help?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
> ```

This is probably because you are missing the `L` (`Last`) flag on the redirect directive. It should read:

```
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

(Also, no need to capture the *pattern* `(.*)` if you are not using a backreference in the *substitution*.)

Without the `L` flag, processing continues through the file and it looks like it's possibly being caught by your later rewrite. But the previous directive has already set the 3xx status, so it ends up rewriting the URL again and then redirecting.

Although I think something may have got lost in your example, as you have switched between `.com` and `.net` domains? You are missing the TLD off the first condition in your rewrite and where did the `/myfolder-public` go in the erroneous redirect?